# Перенос обработчика события

Tags: c#, wpf, .net, xaml

При создании обработчика события в xaml разметке, он появляется в файле name.xaml.cs. Я хочу перенести этот обработчик в класс Editor. В конструкторе я написал DataContext = new Editor(). Что мне нужно сделать, чтобы устанавливать из xaml, напрямую, обработчик события из данного экземпляра класса Editor?

Comment: попробуйте посмотреть в сторону паттерна MVVM и использовать Command для обработки событий. Тогда в code-behind не будет практически никакой логики, она будет во ViewModel.

Answer (score 5):

Синтаксис `Event="Control_OnEvent"` работает только для корневого класса, который и описывается в .xaml+.xaml.cs. Чтобы делегировать обработку другому объекту, просто вызовите соответствующий метод в этом обработчике:

```
class MyWindow {
  Editor editor;
  MyWindow() {
    editor = new Editor();
  }
  void Control_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    editor.DoSomething();
  }
}
```

Трогать `DataContext` не надо.

Answer (score 2):

Из `XAML` подписку уберите, а в коде пишите что-то типа такого:

```
var editor = new Editor();
myButton.Click += editor.EventHandler;
DataContext = editor;
```